# ML- How do I split the follow-up image dataset?

Tags: python, validation, split, deep-learning, dataset

I apologize in advance if I have a duplicate question.

I am working on a MRI image segmentation project using deep learning. 
Among the data I have, MRI taken by the same patient the other day is included. (follow up data)

Ex:

> Patient1(03/05/2017), Patient1(05/06/2018), Patient1(06/15/2019),
>
> Patient2(01/12/2019), Patient2(11/18/2020),
>
> Patient3(01/01/2017), Patient3(02/11/2019), Patient3(12/22/2020),

...

When I divide these data into a training set and validation set, I think that random division will cause generalization problems.

However, I think that it can be considered as another sample if strictly observed (voxel value, spatial difference, etc.)

Summary: Is it okay to split randomly when splitting MRI images for follow up data?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends on how large your dataset is. If you have thousands of images, you can safely perform a random split.

Comment: Oh! My dataset is small, so I am in trouble.